# postgresql offset specific column

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to select after `ArticleId` specific offset as start

```
e.g start from 28 get 28, 27, 26

offset = 28;
limit = 3;

var query = 'SELECT * FROM "Article" ORDER BY "PublishDate" DESC LIMIT $2 OFFSET $1';

ArticleId | PublishDate

25 | "2015-08-19 15:33:37"
26 | "2015-08-19 17:05:42"
27 | "2015-08-19 17:06:05"
28 | "2015-08-19 17:06:22"
29 | "2015-07-19 17:06:46"
30 | "2015-08-19 17:08:11"
```

Comment: start from 26: offset 26 limit 3

Comment: Whether 28 is the order of `ArticleId` based on `PublishDate` or value of `ArticleId`

Comment: @Indian value of `ArticleId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is a value of `ArticleId` you can do this in `where` clause Try this

```
SELECT * 
FROM Article 
where ArticleId >= 28 and ArticleId <= 28 + 3
```

or If `ArticleId` is not consecutive

```
SELECT * 
FROM Article 
where ArticleId >= 28 
Order by ArticleId Limit 3
```

Comment: Yes, that's the straight-forward way, provided the article IDs are consecutive.

Answer (score 1):

The "offset" is simply the ArticleId you should limit in your WHERE clause:

```
var query = 'SELECT * FROM "Article" WHERE ArticleId >= $1 ORDER BY "PublishDate" DESC LIMIT $2';
```